# SQL help - Updating a field in one table to match a field in another table based on matching a different field

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Appreciate any help.  I'm working on a db that was designed a bit poorly.  I need to fix some bad data by updating one table based on another as follows (I am loosely describing the SQL I need):

Two tables:

- **`Airports`** - includes fields: `lat`, `lon`, `airport_id`.
- **`Events`** - includes fields: `lat`, `lon`, `airport_id`.

I want to update the (currently incorrect) events table `lat` and `lon` to the (correct) airports table lat and lon.

Basically: `UPDATE events WHERE <events.airport_id = airports.airport_id> SET events.lat = airports.lat`

Then I can run it again for the lon.

I know I'm close, but not there with the exact syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
UPDATE events e
set    e.lat = (select a.lat from airports a where a.airport_id = e.airport_id),
       e.lon = (select a.lon from airports a where a.airport_id = e.airport_id)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are close, but you need to [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) with `JOIN`. Here is right syntax for that:

```
UPDATE events AS e
INNER JOIN Airports AS a ON e.airport_id = a.airport_id
SET e.lat = a.lat,
    e.lon = a.lon;
```

You put the table references, the updated table which is specified in the `UPDATE` clause with the `JOIN`ed tables directly after the `UPDATE` clause then after that the `SET` clause, you can also include an optional `WHERE` clause at the end.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks SO much for the timely help!  All fixed!